# parametric fillets or chambers

Tags: modeling

I want to make a fillet parametric in the corner with a s I know it has been done.
I have seen an example but cannot repreduce it.

Looking forward towards your reply,

Rik[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107620/discussion-on-question-by-rik-parametric-fillets-or-chambers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So let say you have your shape.

- In *Edit* mode, select an edge and bevel it.

[image]

- Back to *Object* mode, create one shapekey (*Basis*) then a second one.

[image]

- Keep the second shapekey selected. Back to *Edit* mode, select the corner and scale it down with <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>X</kbd> so that it doesn't scale on the X axis.

[image]

- Enable the Snap tool, Vertex mode. Move the bevel on the Z axis (<kbd>G</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>), use the snap to align to the right level. Then move the bevel on the Y axis (<kbd>G</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>), use the snap to align to the right level.

[image]

- Now back to *Object* mode, when you select the second shapekey and play with the Value, the bevel shrinks to its new radius.

[image]

Comment: Many thanks to moonboots, I think I can go further

Comment: I might have some work for you, willing to pay for it. Lets just say I'm a beginner and want to master blender fully. I can duplicate your example but have a few questions left. The radius doen't stay tangent to the surface when I change it, also the radius itself or the ammount of segments can not be steered. (not sure if thats in the model I send you).

Comment: Don't forget when you scale down to prevent any scaling on the X axis with shift X. The amount of segments of the bevel can't be changed.

Comment: @rik Hello and welcome. Please don't add thank you as a comment, upvote the answer instead. If you feel it completely solved your problem consider marking it accepted

Comment: and to me more specific of my problem. Here is a webgl based configurator that (probably) works with shape keyshttps://faustlinoleum.com/en/product/tables/beam-linoleum-table-designed-by-daniel-lorch

Comment: how do I upvote?

Comment: on the top left of my answer there's a check sign  ;)

Comment: done, I havent quite found the answer, but came a bit further. To really answer what I want check out my second post. I'm not sure wether blender is capable of it

Comment: Hey @rik :). You can also mark the answer as accepted **✓** if it solved your problem :).